# Selecting items defined as enum in a list C#

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

I am a beginner in C#. What I want to do is return a list of 4 items. I map the Ebook items defined as an enum in BookList and I just want to return these items defined as an enum. However, there are multiple properties in the Lib class. I just don't know how to return them from the list.

If I do the same as in the commented line, all the properties in the list return. Also, I cannot return other enum items. I don't know how to do this.

Here is my mapping part:

```
public static Book Map(Tax tax)
{
    Book b = new Book();
    b.BookList.Where(x => x.BookType == EBook.Type1).FirstOrDefault().Dual = tax.TaxType1;
    b.BookList.Where(x => x.BookType == EBook.Type2).FirstOrDefault().Dual = tax.TaxType2;

    b.BookList = new List<Lib> { new Lib() { BookType = EBook.Type1 } }; //here
}
```

Book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book();
    public List<Lib> BookList { get; set; }
}
```

Lib Class:

```
public class Lib: ILib
{
    public EBook BookType;
    public double Dual;
    .....
}
```

Ebook part:

```
public enum EBook
{
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    Type3 = 3,
    Type4 = 4
}
```

Tax class:

```
public interface Tax
{
    double TaxType1 { get; set; }
    double TaxType2 { get; set; }
    double TaxType3 { get; set; }
    double TaxType4 { get; set; }
}
```

The json returning from Postman should look like this:

```js
"BookList": [
{
    "Type1": 12.4,
    "Type2": 15.5,
    "Type3": 10.8,
    "Type4": 7.55
}]
```

It should return the corresponding TaxType values of the items defined as an enum.

Comment: Does the code even run? It seems there's errant ) after Dual

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. The problem is still the same

Comment: Can you edit the question with what are you expecting to be returned from Map() ? Perhaps an example of the actual scenario

Comment: Okay, I edited. I tried to explain a little more

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you'd have to include Tax classes and the classes where you're going to return the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just need to create a `Lib` for each BookType with the respective TaxType:

```
b.BookList = new List<Lib> 
{ 
    new Lib { BookType = EBook.Type1, Dual = tax.TaxType1 },
    new Lib { BookType = EBook.Type2, Dual = tax.TaxType2 },
    new Lib { BookType = EBook.Type3, Dual = tax.TaxType3 },
    new Lib { BookType = EBook.Type4, Dual = tax.TaxType4 }
};
```